Box-shadow on the reflected element
When hovering over an element, the box-shadow property is correctly applied to the main element (the one on top). However, the reflected element ends up with an unattractive square border because it cannot identify box-shadow as a light scattering property. How can I remove this semi-transparent square border from the reflected element and make its reflection look nice?


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.codetheworld-io {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: var(--color);
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 10px linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));

}

a:hover {
  background: var(--color);
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--color), 0 0 25px var(--color), 0 0 50px var(--color), 0 0 200px var(--color);
}
<div class="codetheworld-io">
  <a href="#" style="--color: #0072b1">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--color: #E1306C">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--color: #FF0050">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="--color: #4267B2">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a6d498a7e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




Thank you, its very good idea! But within this preview it doesnt show the behavior of elements, that was applied. It could be because of WebKit, I think

Your webkit line was incomplete. I fixed it

Yes, already works all properly. Thank you very much!

You cannot really "remove" the square box, since the reflection isn't a proper element and it's rendering is limited to the size of your origin-element.
You can only try to contain your shadow within the origin-elemnt of the reflection.
To achieve this you will need an additional wrapper around the element you have your effects on (a-tag in your case).
You can add padding to this wrapper and use this bigger container to reflect your actual element + effects. You would need to cut back on some of your box-shadow spread for that to still properly work.
I added an example as snippet, but the reflection doesn't seem to work within the preview, so here is a jsfiddle with a working example:
JSFiddle


body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.codetheworld-io {
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper{
    padding:25px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    margin-right:-25px;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below -25px linear-gradient(transparent, white);
}
a {
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: var(--color);

}

a:hover {
    background: var(--color);
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--color), 0 0 25px var(--color), 0 0 25px var(--color), 0 0 20px var(--color);
}
<div class="codetheworld-io">
    <a href="#" style="--color: #0072b1">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="--color: #E1306C">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="--color: #FF0050">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="--color: #4267B2">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a6d498a7e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




Thank you very much! It is exactly what I want. But I didn`t quite understand how did you achieve it. Could you please explain it more detail. It would be very helpful for me. Thanks :)

How is this exactly what you want if you use reflect? It does not reflect anymore

@mplungjan in the class wrapper was -webkit-box-reflect involved. It could to perform different behaviour, but essentially it is what I wanted to achieve

@НікітаГончарук if you add a border to your wrapper-class you can see the box in which you can render your reflection content. Since your box-shadow was going beyond the boundaries of the reflected element it stopped propagating at the edges of the element box.
Since the box-shadow is now contained within the boundaries of the wrapper class your shadow doesn't reach the edge of your reflection and therefore does't create the box-shape. Hope this explains it a bit better.

@Christoph Kern, as far as I understand, box-shadow doesnt reach the edges of the element that is to say the box-shadow is already a little smaller, so the right angles we dont see, because the box-shadow is not so big in order to reach this angles and it is stopping on the way to reaching the edges, so to speak?
